# Can I submit to the same Single Thread Executor multiple times?

Tags: java, multithreading, retrofit2, executorservice, completable-future

I have a block of code that should be run in parallel on different threads using `CompletableFuture` and `ExecutorService`. The block of code makes network requests (Using RetroFit), and waits for each network request to finish before going on to make the next request, etc. Can I call `SingleThreadExecutor#submit()` multiple times, passing around that executor?

I want to ensure all parallel runs of this block of code get their own thread and run all their operations on that thread.

Basically the block of code should act like synchronous code, but have multiple instance of this block running in parallel, each instance on it's own thread.

Currently, the program just idles when we make a call from the `Service` and I suspect it has to do with passing around the same `SingleThreadExecutor` but am a bit stuck.

```
ArrayList<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        Future<List<String>> stringListFuture = myStringService.getStringList(executor);
        // We begin stalling once the next line gets hit.
        List<String> stringList = stringListFuture.get();
        
        Future<Integer> integerDataFuture = myIntegerService.getInteger(executor);
        Integer integerData = integerDataFuture.get();

        executor.shutdown();
    }, executor);

    futures.add(future);
}

CompletableFuture<Void> completableFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
        completableFutures.join();

// Do something after all blocks of code have finished running in parallel.
```

```
class MyStringFuture {
    public Future<List<String>> getStringList(ExecutorService executor) {

        // Could these nested uses of the same executor be the problem?
        Future<Double> doubeDataFuture = doubleDataService.getFuture();
        Double doubleData = doubeDataFuture.get(executor);

        Call<List<Dividend>> data = retrofit.create(Api.class).getData(doubleData);

        return executor.submit(() -> data.execute().body());
    }
}
```

Comment: "Currently, the program just idles" take a thread dump so you can see what's happening.

Comment: And please write a minimal, runnable example which illustrates the problem.

Comment: Your second and third paragraphs are contradictory. Edit to clarify.

Comment: Are you aware of [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) in Java 21+? There is generally no need to write complicated async code with `CompletableFuture` anymore. Just write your task as plain sequential code, as a single `Runnable`/`Callable` task, and submit to an executor service backed by virtual threads. Vastly simpler code, easy to debug, and extremely performant.

Comment: "Basically the block of code should act like synchronous code, but have multiple instance of this block running in parallel, each instance on it's own thread." All this is just a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Your code is never going end as it submits a task to single thread executor from a task already running in the same single thread executor. The sub-task can never start until the first task ends, but the first task is awaiting the end by calling `future.get()`, which of course blocks indefinitely because it is never started.

Comment: "I have a block of code that should be run in parallel..." How does "run in parallel" mean anything if you don't let it run in parallel with anything else? Your example is incomplete, but it looks as if, in every place where you submit a task to the executor, the very next thing you do is _wait_ for the task to complete. If that's really true, then you're setting up the task to run "in parallel" with the caller, who is doing _nothing._ You might just as well simply call the task function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using a single thread executor task which submits another task to same single thread executor, and then awaits that sub-task to exit. It is the same as this example which would print "ONE" and "THREE", and never print "TWO", "cf" or "FOUR":

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    log("ONE");
    // This subtask can never start while current task is still running:
    Future<?> cf = executor.submit(() -> log("TWO"));
    log("THREE");
    try
    {
        // Blocks forever if run from single thread executor:
        log("cf"+cf.get());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("It failed");
    }
    log("FOUR");
}, executor);
```

The subtask could only run after the main task exits - if "FOUR" was printed - but is stuck awaiting `cf.get()`.

The solution is easy - you should process the initial task on separate Thread or executor queue to the service used by the sub-tasks, or chain each component of the subtasks with `.thenRun(...)`.

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(subtask1, executor)
                                                  .thenRun(subtask2);
```